# How do I set a default zoom in a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I have a WKWebView setup to display contents of a CSV file. It works fine but the content is zoomed out a lot requiring the user to zoom in.

Is there a way to set a default zoom in a WKWebView? So that when its displayed, the content is already zoomed in an x amount?

I already tried setting a `minimumZoomScale` on the webview's scrollview but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Did you set the `zoomScale` to your scrollView then?
`webView.scrollView.zoomScale = 'your default'`

It won't work if you only set the `minimumZoomScale`.

Comment: Thanks I got it. Had to do ```webView.scrollView.setZoomScale(scale: CGFloat, animated: Bool)``` inside of ```viewDidAppear```